# How to embed a jquery library in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery library code in jquery.xyz.js . 
I have an html file which uses the function defined in jquery.xyz.js in this manner .

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("This is my first JavaScript!");
$(function(){ $("ul#xy01").xyz(); }); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But the jQuery is not running, which I am assuming because I haven't loaded the jQuery properly onto the html page. So how do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

See [how jQuery works](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) in the manual for the basics, and the [download page](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) to fetch the library (or to find out addresses for direct linking on a Content Delivery Network).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include the script files before using functions defined in them (`$` is just a function), for example:

```
<html>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.xyz.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){ $("ul#xy01").xyz(); }); 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Be sure to include jQuery **before** plugins that rely on it, or you'll get some errors first thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function () {
 //do stuff with the script

};
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/xx.xx/jquery.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="PATH TO YOUR JS FILE"></script>
```

Stick this above your jQuery code in the `<head></head>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">   
</script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("This is my first JavaScript!");
$(function(){ $("ul#xy01").xyz(); }); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```